# how should i validate first four digits as a character and last three digits as number in the field container number in oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

how should i validate first four digits as a character and last three digits as number in the field of container number by oracle forms

i tried like below

`begin
    if container_number is null then
    error message;
    else
    for i in 1..length(:xxms_xp_shippingout_line.container_number)
    v_length:=substr(:xxms_xp_shippingout_line.container_number,i,4);
    v_length1:=substr(:xxms_xp_shippingout_line.container_number,i,5);
    loop
    if v_length is not between 'A' and 'Z' then
    error message;
    if v_length1 is not between '0' and '9'
    error message;
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;
    end;`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a db function to check this for you with regular expression:
see following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)